# Tier prices not displaying

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-view, tierprice

Ive installed a new magento theme/template from Template monster and I updated my magento to the latest 1.9.3 version of Magento and then installed.

Ive noticed that My tier prices dont show on the product page.  It did and does on the old theme.  Template monster say as the template is compatible with 1.9.2 they cant help.

Any ideas on how to get the tier pricing to show again on page view?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I will give you two files to check them, basically the themes can customise the different design of pages widjets, css etc add blocks but not remove the **natif Magento blocks!** So please check these files from your new theme and comapre theme with the old one which it's worked.

```
1. app/design/frontend/{package-name}/{theme-name}/frontend/catalog/product/view.phtml

2. app/design/frontend/{package-name}/{theme-name}/frontend/catalog/product/price.phtml
```

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your reply.  Unfortunately ive removed the old template files so cant reference it to the old working version :(

Comment: Compare it to the base one `app/design/frontend/base/default`

Comment: Ok will do, thank you.  Am I looking out for a particular string of code that might be missing?